# Saving a remote variable locally with heredoc through ssh

Tags: bash, shell, eof, heredoc

I am trying to run a local function remotely on a machine and retrieve the values of multiple variables of this function in a local function.

The first line of the heredoc section enables me to run the function remotely by defining it on the remote machine.

With the local machine named `localmach` and the remote machine named `remotemach`

```bash
#! /bin/bash

arr=()

scanHost()
{
  arr+=("$(hostname)")
  tmpResult=$(hostname)
}

scanHost

ssh user@remotemach "bash -s --" <<EOF
$(typeset -f scanHost)
tmpResult=$tmpResult
scanHost
EOF

echo "Local array -> ${arr[@]}"
echo "Local echo  -> $tmpResult"
```

The snippet above returns

```
Local array -> localmach
Local echo  -> localmach
```

But what I need is

```
Local array -> localmach remotemach
Local echo  -> remotemach
```

In words, I need the value of the remote `tmpResult` AND the array `arr` stored locally.

Addendum :
Here I make the command `hostname` as an example, but in reality I am "scanning" a remote host and generate a JSON string that I store in the tmpResult variable. If I encounter problems during the scan, I append a string explaining the issue in `arr`. This way in my final json I can list all the problems encountered during the scan of multiple hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect the result of `ssh` command :

```
#! /bin/bash

scanHost()
{
  tmpResult=$(hostname)
}

scanHost

tmpResult=$(ssh user@remotemach "bash -s" <<EOF
$(typeset -f scanHost)
scanHost
echo "\$tmpResult"
EOF
)

echo "Local echo -> $tmpResult"
```

**New Version**

```
#! /bin/bash

arr=()

scanHost()
{
  arr+=("$(hostname)")
  tmpResult=$(hostname)
}

scanHost

eval "$(ssh user@remotemach "bash -s" <<EOF
$(typeset -f scanHost)
$(declare -p arr)
scanHost
declare -p arr
declare -p tmpResult
EOF
)"

echo "Local array -> ${arr[@]}"
echo "Local echo  -> $tmpResult"
```

Use `eval` with caution due to side effects.

Comment: I'm realizing I was not precise enough in my question. Your answer works but I actually have an array of strings of errors encountered during the scan. Thus my need to get the variable value instead of collecting the result.
I will update my question to include this.

Comment: Great thank you for the quick help !
As a side note, my VIM colorscheme is struggling and parses the file wrongly because of the subshell call "$(ssh [...])", which induced my into thinking my tests were false before.

Comment: Quick followup question : What if I wanted to get the return value of the ssh, or it's error message ?